# Cell location in Personal Hotspot mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to capture `UITablViewCell` location in Personal Hotspot mode after clicking the cell. As you know there is larger blue status bar in that mode. When I use:

```
 CGRect cellRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 cellRect = CGRectOffset(cellRect, -tableView.contentOffset.x, -tableView.contentOffset.y);
```

It returns me not the correct location of cell that I press on. Its correct without personal hotspot. I am wondering how to solve this.

Comment: Please describe more detailed. Expected behaviour, actual behaviour, what "personal hotspot"?

Comment: I have a bit changed my post. When I press on the cell in hotspot mode, its not returning correct CGRect.